# Using MS graph API in production environment

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I am integrating Onenote with my application. I am using MS Graph API's for getting data from Onenote. To consume the api's I am generating the token as mentioned at link [get auth tokens](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2).

I am registering my application at [MS application registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/). Do we need to purchase any kind of paid license to use services provided by MS graph API's.

The app registration process seems simple and doesn't differentiate between applications that can be used in production/test environment.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2

Follow it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Prateek. I am using Azure AD v2.0 for authentication. Registered the app using same process but wanted to make sure that we don't need any explicit licensing from Microsoft apart from this registration process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The app registration process seems simple and doesn't differentiate
>   between applications that can be used in production/test environment.

Apps registered in the app registration portal can be used for production or test environments. There isn't any switch that needs to be set when you're ready to ship.  Congrats on shipping your app to production!

> Do we need to purchase any kind of paid license to use services
>   provided by MS graph API's.

We don't charge for access to the API.  Some of the services exposed in Graph via APIs require licenses like Intune.  It sounds like you're using OneNote so as long as users of your app are already using OneNote you're fine to access their notes via our API.  Just be sure not to DDOS us :)

If you can share, our community would love to hear about your app!

Comment: Thanks for the response Dan.